# Android http POST getting UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL

Tags: php, android, http, post, upload

My android app is sending a large file (more or less 50mb) using HTTP Post
here is my code:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
        String responseLine = null;
        try {
            MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            entity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(mFile));
            httpPost.setEntity(entity.build());
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);

            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

            // if the response from my server is length = 2 that means everything
            // went ok
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK &&   response.getEntity().getContentLength() == 2) {

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          //blabla..
        }

        return "ok";
    }
```

the upload php code on my server;

```
 // log in files
 file_put_contents( 'screen/debug' . time() . '.log', var_export( $_FILES, true));
     $objFile = $_FILES["file"];
        $target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/test/" . basename($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

        if( move_uploaded_file( $objFile["tmp_name"], $target_path) ) {
            print "ok";
        } else {
            print "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }
```

SO this piece of code works quite well most of time. BUT sometimes (too often to ignore) the upload fails. In my server errors logs I get the PHP error **UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL**

My server is a test server with
upload_max_filesize = 400M
post_max_size = 512M
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 3600   ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = 1024M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume

Does anybody sees why I could get this error ?

Comment: could you post LOGCAT Error ??

Comment: No logcat error, as I personally can't reproduce the error....I'am just seeing that files are not getting uploaded and that I have that UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL error...